# Remote register regsvr32 using powershell

Tags: powershell, regsvr32

I'm trying to register(regsvr32) a library(OraOLEDB10.dll) on a remote computer running Windows 10 using PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer_name -ScriptBlock {regsvr32 /s c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\OraOLEDB10.dll}
```

After execution, the command does not return anything, but the library is not registered either.
The library files are present on the remote computer.

Comment: I guess you don't have access rights, see: [Powershell to display Regsvr32 result in console instead of dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37110642/1701026)

Comment: If I use the - Credential, the result is the same.

Comment: Where in the link provided by iRon was the -Credential parameter even mentioned? Just because you pass credentials explicitly does not mean that user has correct permissions on the target system

Comment: In the link provided by iRon there is an example of registering a local library and I was unable to adapt this script to execution on a remote computer. As for the rights, the shell was launched as an administrator (domain administrator) and in -Credential indicated the domain administrator's information. Very strange shell behavior, not returning an error or success message.

Comment: Something like: `computer_name -ScriptBlock { $regsvrp = Start-Process regsvr32.exe -ArgumentList "/s c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\OraOLEDB10.dll" -PassThru; $regsvrp.WaitForExit(5000); $regsvrp.ExitCode }` which should return an exit code (`0` if successful).

Comment: Iron, thank you very much. After running the script I got:
`True
0`
But the library did not register.
If i open a command prompt locally from remote computer as an administrator and run:
`regsvr32.exe "c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\OraOLEDB10.dll"`
Then the library is registered.

Comment: How do you [determine it is registerd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689180/1701026)? What if you check this registry key remotely?

Comment: On the server where the library is manually registered, an entry is added to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0BB9AFD1-51A1-11D2-BB7D-00C04FA30080}`.
When executed via powershell, the entry does not appear.

Comment: Run script as admin.

Comment: jdweng, powershell run as administrator

Comment: If everything said here is true then my gut says that the oracle dll is perhaps needing remote access to some other system and thus it's the double-hop issue. That's the only thing that makes sense to me so far.

Comment: There is probably a problem with WinRM. If I execute `Invoke-Command –ComputerName my_pc –ScriptBlock { Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:Software'}` while on my_pc, then similarly the console does not return anything. But if I execute `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:Software'` while in the same console, I get the desired result.